S-parameters of a matching network
I have the following matching network designed for \$\omega=2\pi\cdot 1GHz\$ and I want to calculate \$S_{11}\$ and \$S_{21}\$. The normal definitions/calculation setup for S11 that I use are in the screenshot below (taken from this set of slides).
According to that procedure, to calculate e.g. \$S_{11}\$ I would have to add a resistor of value \$R_S=50\$ to the output port. What I'm unsure about here is that the matching network is designed to transform the load from 200 ohms to 50 ohms, but the network doesn't work for other values of load resistance. So if I attached an extra termination resistor to the output port, then the resistance looking into the matching network is no longer equal to \$R_S\$, but that's just because of the measurement setup. And if I replaced the original load resistance with a 50-ohm termination that also messes up the input resistance. It seems like the right thing to do is leave the output port as it is instead of changing anything, but then it seems like I'm just changing the definition of the S-parameters to suit the current situation.
Am I misunderstanding something about the S-parameter definitions here?



You need to distinguish between the use of your network, and what you might do in measurement, design and verification.
In use, of course its output will be loaded in a nominal 200 Ω. If you want to measure its input impedance when loaded with that, then load the output with 200 Ω, and measure the one-port S11 of the input with a 50 Ω analyser. It should be what you calculate/simulate it should be, based on the component values and a 200 Ω load. You can't measure the other S parameters directly, as you don't have a 200 Ω port on your analyser.
If you want to verify that your matching network has been built as you designed it, then it's quite reasonable to measure it in a completely 50 Ω system, with a 2-port analyser, measuring all four S parameters. Of course the S11 will be different to the use case, because the output is loaded differently. However, it should be what you calculate/simulate it should be, based on the component values and a 50 Ω load.
Sometimes, designers will connect two identical matching networks back to back, ideally with an attenuator between them to tame any errors (an attenuator designed for those port impedances), and then two 50 Ω ports are available for a full four port measurement.

Thank you for the info. When you mention "the one-port S11 with a 50 ohm analyser", does this refer to the quantity: (Zin-50)/(Zin+50), where Zin is the input impedance of the matching network when loaded with 200 ohms, or is this something else?

S11 is defined as the ratio of the reflected signal to incident signal at port 1, when all other ports are loaded with what you want to load them with. So it will be different when the output is loaded with 50 or 200 ohms. The z-50 formula you quote looks plausible, I might check it if I get the time.
